# Admob interstital ads not displaying in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, admob

Hi I am trying to display interstital ads using admob but it's not displaying the ads. 
   My code is as follows

```
  import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
  import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID="ca-app-pub-21740939xxxxx";
  private InterstitialAd interstitial;
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    displayInterstitial();
  }
   public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }
  }
```

In manifest I declared permissions:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But it's not displaying. Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Please help us helping you, and post logs !

Comment: @Orabîg in logs, i didn't get any crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess while you are displaying your ad it is not loaded yet , so try this

```
interstitial= new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build();
}

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
        interstitial.show();  // you can call this anywhere you want 

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);

    }

});
```

Comment: how you are overriding? @Kunu in new google play service i couldn't find that..it's not overriding when i use AdListener.interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    
    }

Comment: just copy that override part and see what error you are getting and I am also using new google play service and you can override it in there

Comment: ads not displaying. :(

Comment: thanks @Kunu actually i didn't declare this.   <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"/> now it's working.. thank you so much.

Comment: Do NOT call interstitial.show() from onAdLoaded(). You will infuriate your users and probably get your account banned. Call interstitial.show() at a natural break point in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can only display the ad after it is loaded. When you are calling `displayInterstitial()`, your ad may not be loaded. Register for a listener and that will tell you  when the loading is done.

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
    public void onAdLoaded(){
        displayInterstitial();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. onAddLoaded() method is not overriding by AdListener() and more over by adding that method, doesn't provide any change as it shows onAdLoaded() never used locally.

Comment: Try adding @override annotation before onAdLoaded() function. com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener does have onAdLoaded() method.

Comment: Do NOT call interstitial.show() from onAdLoaded(). You will infuriate your users and probably get your account banned. Call interstitial.show() at a natural break point in your app

Comment: Yes, of course. The idea here was to let the OP know that he must display the interstitial after the ad is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to display interstitial ad. It works perfect for me.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(“**************************”);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
          public void onAdLoaded(){
               displayInterstitial();
          }
});
}

public void displayInterstitial() {
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
  interstitial.show();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do NOT call interstitial.show() from onAdLoaded(). You will infuriate your users and probably get your account banned. Call interstitial.show() at a natural break point in your app