# Interstitial Ad not showing (with Banner ads)

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I tried to add the code as per Google ADMOB Ads but it didn't work. Then I started working with GITHUB example to add Interstitial ads. I have no errors whatsoever in my project. Eclipse shows nothing in place of ads. Please have a look at my code and tell me where am I going wrong. I will highlight stuff wherever necessary. BANNER ADS ARE WORKING!!!!

```
public class AppGame extends Activity {


AdView adView;

 /** The log tag. */
  private static final String LOG_TAG = "InterstitialSample";

  /** Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID1 = "INSERT AD ID HERE";

  /** The interstitial ad. */
  private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID1);

    // Set the AdListener.
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded");

      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {


        // Change the button text and disable the button.

      }
    });

}



/** Called when the Load Interstitial button is clicked. */
  public void loadInterstitial(View unusedView) {
    // Disable the show button until the new ad is loaded.

    // Check the logcat output for your hashed device ID to get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();

    // Load the interstitial ad.
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  /** Called when the Show Interstitial button is clicked. */
  public void showInterstitial(View unusedView) {
    // Disable the show button until another interstitial is loaded.


    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      interstitialAd.show();
    } else {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown.");
    }
  }

  /** Gets a string error reason from an error code. */
  private String getErrorReason(int errorCode) {
    String errorReason = "";
    switch(errorCode) {
      case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        errorReason = "Internal error";
        break;
      case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST:
        errorReason = "Invalid request";
        break;
      case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR:
        errorReason = "Network Error";
        break;
      case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:
        errorReason = "No fill";
        break;
    }
    return errorReason;
  }

  }
```

Comment: You have given internet permission as well as declared ` <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"/>` in your manifest , right ?

Comment: Banner ads are working! Only interstitial ads aren't.

Comment: Then please post code only related to Interstitial ads

Comment: Please check my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474475/admob-interstital-ads-not-displaying-in-android/25474758#25474758) answer

Comment: @Kunu I checked and tried. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Call `loadInterstitial(v)` after setting setting the adunit:

```
 interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID1);
 loadInterstitial(v);
```

And call `showInterstitial(v)` when/where you want to show the ad:

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the `loadInterstitial` function for the interstitial ad to load.

In your `onCreate` function, call the `loadInterstitial` function. Then add the listener to it like so:

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded");
        interstitialAd.show();
      }
```

or set a boolean to true and at a natural breakpoint in your app, check if the boolean is true and then show the ad.

Comment: You are right but how do I do that. I think I have to add it like this:
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAdLoaded() {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded");
         View v = null;
         loadInterstitial(v);
       }

Comment: Please don't instruct people to call ```interstitial.show()``` from ```#onAdLoaded()``` is provides poor UX and is likely to get their accounts banned

Comment: I agree @William but as he is currently having a prototype, this will show that the ad does get loaded. It is indeed poor practice, hence my sentence about the natural breakpoint.

Comment: Sure, but he's going to copy your code. And that is going to get his account banned. Please don't perpetuate this bad code example.

Comment: No his account will not get banned by admobs if he uses this kind of code in his app. People will most likely get irritated and uninstall the app or give a bad rating, but you will not get banned for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my one of the testing device. I searched so many days. But i didn't get any solution.

At last I tried by removing the code

```
.addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
```

and I got successful result.

So try like this at last step of testing.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate add below lines

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        // set the ad unit ID
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Ads loaded, stop requesting
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
               //update time start
                    timeStart = new Date().getTime();
            }
        });
```

onResume check time show Intertitial Ads and send request Ads:

```
  if(new Date().getTime()-timeStart>=timeShowAds) {
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .addTestDevice("36E0B62FE34536712ED1BEBD85467085")
              .build();
      // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```